# Configurations for activity_main.xml must agree on the root element's ID. Missing ID: - layout @+id/drawer_layout: - layout-land

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, drawerlayout, android-viewbinding, android-include

Im using viewbinding, and i get this error when i build

```
Configurations for activity_main.xml must agree on the root element's ID.

Missing ID:
 - layout

@+id/drawer_layout:
 - layout-land
```

It says i need to have two different id for rootview. But i have different root for portrait layout and landscape layout. Like below. If i put same `id` to drawerlayout(landscape) and same `id` for constraintlayout(portrait) it creates problem in code. That to i wrote common code without checking orientation.
How to get rid of this error, using `<include id>` or `<merge>` or anyother ways?
(i dont know how these works exactly for my needs) without checking orientations in code blocks.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/purple_500"
        android:theme="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <fragment
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottom_nav"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_nav"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/nav_host_fragment"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_navigation" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**land/activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?colorPrimary"
            android:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme" />

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation"
            app:defaultNavHost="true" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_navigation" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**code**

```
NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, drawerLayout)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a `</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>` for the portrait and a `</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>` for the landscape orientation. Hence the error.. You can try running the app after wrapping the drawer layout in a constraint layout and giving each an identical id

Comment: The view type doesn't matter, only the name of the ID needs to be the same.